# Activity of android

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I am working with the xml file ,through which i am accessing a string through a variable passkey.later i am assigning it to strPassword. i am getting error for setListAdapter.Here is my code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="passkey">
  <item>1234</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

and

```
public class AdminLogin extends Activity 
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle bdlActivity)
    {  
        String[] strPassword = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.passkey);

         setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.adminlogin,
              R.id.Editpassword, strPassword))
       //button events
     }
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please edit your question and add the logcat output.

Comment: You should avoid storing any password in plain text.

Comment: my error is :The method setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>) is undefined for the type AdminLogin

Comment: you need a ListView / ListActivity, and attach an adapter to them!

Comment: No  actually i am not using ListActivity , can i do it in Activity

Comment: @sameer you can't call `setListAdapter` in an `Activity`, if you want to use that method you need to use a [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Comment: you can do it, check out my update. you may have a `ListView` inside an `Activity`, and set its adapter properly will solve your problem. You only need to set the activity's content view: `setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend your class with `ListActivty`. You cant instantiate ListView in simple activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from a simple Activity too:

say you have a main layout, like: 
**mylayout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_ok" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="OK" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/btn_ok" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This would be the layout of your activity, with a list view inside of it (`@id/listview`)

Your `Activity`'s `onCreate` method should look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.adminlogin,
              R.id.Editpassword, strPassword))
}
```